# Security/permission at the highest level?

Tags: trello, permissions

When I first browse to trello.com there is no request for login or password or any screening of any kind. The result is that anyone sitting at my PC can click on the Trello icon/shortcut and be presented with the full list of all boards I have created, ie., Trello assumes that the PC operator is always me.

How do I stop access to the main Trello screen listing the boards I have created?

Example: if someone operates my PC and browses to yahoo.com or even my.yahoo.com they are not presented with all my activity. In fact they would not even know if I had a Yahoo account.

How do I force a logon to my "home" page on Trello?

Comment: I suppose logging out when you are finished using Trello isn't what you are after?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I missed the Log-out function completely.

Answer (score 1):

Trello (like many sites) uses cookies to identify you, so you don't have to type in your username and password every time you visit (very handy for frequently visited sites).

If you log out, then the cookie gets deleted and you get the standard sign up/login page when you next visit the site.

You can log out by clicking on you avatar in the top-right corner of any page and selecting the last option (Log out).

Comment: thank you for your reply; the log-out (which I missed completely since it was not right in my face) addresses the concern I had for other users on my PC. I was assuming that closing the browser and/or a reboot was accomplishing the task of completely closing the session.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have to remember to log out every time, you could just set your browser to not hold any cookies or cache whenever you close it. This should cause any website you visit to require you log back in whenever you re-open your browser.

I've set my IE to clear everything for website testing purposes, but you could choose to just clear your cookies for the desired outcome.

[image]